# How to change the marker in yellowbrick plots?

Tags: yellowbrick

As the title suggests, I have some trouble changing the marker style in some of the Yellowbrick plots. For instance, I know it is possible to do so for the ScatterVisualiser, but I would like to do the same for ValidationCurve also.

Is this possible?